# How do not show null in the form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form. Currently, when the user with no email is submitting it, it shows in email field string with the text `null`. How can I make this field empty. Here is the code of email field

```
patientEmail: currentPatient.email ? currentPatient.email : null
```

Comment: Replace `null` with `""`...

Comment: use OR operator for default value ```patientEmail: currentPatient.email || "" ```;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

patientEmail: currentPatient.email ? currentPatient.email : ""

Just replace null with an empty string.